# mongoose.watch() fields' name changing by itself

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, watch

I begin with mongoose and I have to use watch() method on a collection.
When i want to catch insert, there are no problems.
Nevertheless, when I want to retrieve the changes of an update, I don't know why, in some cases, mongoose changes the name of my fields?

```
 registration.watch(). on('change', data => {
  if(data.operationType == "update") {
    console.log(data.updateDescription.updatedFields);
  }
)};
```

my registration's collection is made up of persons who can accept or decline an invitation, and a person can change they answer. So it's basically a removal of the person from one array of data to be put in the other one.

The only problem I have is my array's name sometimes "change" :

```
{
  __v: 100,
  accepted: [
    {
      _id: 5faa76d048dd6e0017e631d4,
      user: 5faa752848dd6e0017e631d2
    },
    {
      _id: 5faa9ab06048a20017774610,
      user: 5fa8fabc60260ec31606d71e
    },
  ],
  'declined.1': { _id: 5faf037a141f030017863484, user: 5faa74de48dd6e0017e631d0 },
```

for example here, my field declined change to "declined.1", why it's happening ? and how to avoid this ? or at least, how can i get declined's array in this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

When you update a document in MongoDB, it only writes the deltas to the operations log, which is what the `watch` function pulls from.

The dot notation `declined.1` means index 1 of the declined array.  The change document you provided would be expected from pushing a new object onto the `declined` array.  Essentially, it is saving space by not repeating all of the array elements that didn't change.

If you need to retrieve the entire document, you could set the `fullDocument` to `updateLookup`.  See http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#watch

Comment: Thanks for your response !
It sounds interesting, I don't really need to entire document, so the default operation of mongoose seems good to me.
if i don't change the fullDocument to updateLoopkup, how could I access directly to the element who was added to declined ? because when I have declined.1, "data.updateDescription.updatedFields.declined" is undefined. 
Could you give me an example please ?

Comment: The field name will be `declined.1`, so perhaps `data.updateDescription.updatedFields["declined.1"]`

Comment: Or if you don't know the index, you could iterate Object.keys of `updatedFields`, matching for `/declined/` to find the key names.